# Bitnami Kafka docker container not starting on Ubuntu

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, docker-compose, ubuntu-22.04, bitnami-kafka

This is the docker-compose.yml file I have prepared to start the bitnami/zookeeper and the bitnami/kafka containers.

```
version: "3.4"

services:
  zookeeper:
    image: bitnami/zookeeper
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
    volumes:
      - "zookeeper_data:/bitnami"
    environment:
      - ALLOW_ANONYMOUS_LOGIN=yes
  kafka:
    image: bitnami/kafka
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    volumes:
      - "kafka_data:/bitnami"
    environment:
      - KAFKA_CFG_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper:2181
      - ALLOW_PLAINTEXT_LISTENER=yes
      - KAFKA_CFG_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://:9092
      - KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper

volumes:
  zookeeper_data:
    driver: local
  kafka_data:
    driver: local
   
networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: techBankNet
```

When I run the command `docker-compose up -d`, it shows no errors. But when I execute `docker ps`, I see that only the zookeeper container is running.

After checking the logs for the bitnami/kafka container, this is the output I found.

```
kafka 14:50:00.34 
kafka 14:50:00.34 Welcome to the Bitnami kafka container
kafka 14:50:00.34 Subscribe to project updates by watching https://github.com/bitnami/containers
kafka 14:50:00.34 Submit issues and feature requests at https://github.com/bitnami/containers/issues
kafka 14:50:00.34 
kafka 14:50:00.34 INFO  ==> ** Starting Kafka setup **
kafka 14:50:00.37 WARN  ==> KAFKA_CFG_LISTENERS must include a listener for CONTROLLER
kafka 14:50:00.37 WARN  ==> You set the environment variable ALLOW_PLAINTEXT_LISTENER=yes. For safety reasons, do not use this flag in a production environment.
kafka 14:50:00.37 INFO  ==> Initializing Kafka...
kafka 14:50:00.38 INFO  ==> No injected configuration files found, creating default config files
kafka 14:50:00.42 INFO  ==> Initializing KRaft...
kafka 14:50:00.42 WARN  ==> KAFKA_KRAFT_CLUSTER_ID not set - If using multiple nodes then you must use the same Cluster ID for each one
kafka 14:50:01.29 INFO  ==> Generated Kafka cluster ID 'W7_NXO5cQXWLs5xG4i7zYw'
kafka 14:50:01.29 INFO  ==> Formatting storage directories to add metadata...
```

I cannot figure out what prevents the bitnami/kafka from starting. I have checked whether any process uses port 9092 and found none. In addition, techBankNet already exists in the docker network list. This is the output of this command, `docker network list`.

```
NETWORK ID     NAME                                 DRIVER    SCOPE
b65deecbaa75   bridge                               bridge    local
5a95427177c5   host                                 host      local
c4243c86eba1   kafka-stack-docker-compose_default   bridge    local
99063d81411a   none                                 null      local
9a1c188071fb   pss-backend-application_pss          bridge    local
5fe91218bb8e   techBankNet                          bridge    local
```

Can anyone give me insights on why the bitnami/kafka docker container fails to start? My OS is KUbuntu 22.04.

Comment: According to the bitnami Github repo, they know the Kafka container is broken and are "working on it". You could use Confluent as an alternative https://github.com/confluentinc/cp-all-in-one/blob/7.4.0-post/cp-all-in-one-community/docker-compose.yml

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [this issue](https://github.com/bitnami/containers/issues/26882) which describes a similar problem (the Bitnami kafka container exiting with an error status but no errors are printed in the log).

You can set `BITNAMI_DEBUG=true` in the environment configuration to see additional logging:

```
kafka:
  image: bitnami/kafka
  ports:
    - "9092:9092"
  volumes:
    - "kafka_data:/bitnami"
  environment:
    - BITNAMI_DEBUG=true
    - KAFKA_CFG_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper:2181
    - ALLOW_PLAINTEXT_LISTENER=yes
    - KAFKA_CFG_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://:9092
    - KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092
  depends_on:
    - zookeeper
```

If I do that and try to bring up your compose configuration, I see:

```
kafka_1      | kafka 15:17:38.39 INFO  ==> Formatting storage directories to add metadata...
kafka_1      | Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: controller.listener.names must contain at least one value appearing in the 'listeners' configuration when running the KRaft controller role
kafka_1      |  at scala.Predef$.require(Predef.scala:281)
kafka_1      |  at kafka.server.KafkaConfig.validateControllerListenerExistsForKRaftController$1(KafkaConfig.scala:2227)
kafka_1      |  at kafka.server.KafkaConfig.validateValues(KafkaConfig.scala:2289)
kafka_1      |  at kafka.server.KafkaConfig.<init>(KafkaConfig.scala:2160)
kafka_1      |  at kafka.server.KafkaConfig.<init>(KafkaConfig.scala:1568)
kafka_1      |  at kafka.tools.StorageTool$.$anonfun$main$1(StorageTool.scala:50)
kafka_1      |  at scala.Option.flatMap(Option.scala:271)
kafka_1      |  at kafka.tools.StorageTool$.main(StorageTool.scala:50)
kafka_1      |  at kafka.tools.StorageTool.main(StorageTool.scala)
container_kafka_1 exited with code 1
```

Making that error message readable without scrolling:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: controller.listener.names must contain at least one value appearing in the 'listeners' configuration when running the KRaft controller role

I don't know enough about Kafka to correct the configuration, but hopefully that's enough to point you in the right direction.

Comment: Yeah, I could see that. The container was up and running when I added this line `- KAFKA_ENABLE_KRAFT=no` under the environments tab. It seems there should be at least one name in the listeners' configuration when in kraft mode.